# How to calculate the area under value x=[2, 4] for SmoothHistogram (PDF)

Tags: numerical-integration, histograms, pdf-format, filling

I have a discrete signal. How can I calculate the area under the curve for $2\le x \le 4$? How can I fill the same area in the plot generated by `SmoothHistogram`?

For Example:

```
r5 = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[1, 2], 100]
p100x = SmoothHistogram[r5, 0.1, "PDF", Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(100\)]\)(x)",}, {"R, \ Ohm",}}, FrameTicks -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{All, All}, {All, All}}, GridLines -> Automatic,  ImageSize -> 600, PlotLegends -> legend, ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"}]
```

[image: SmoothHistogram (PDF)]

Comment: Please check that I interpreted your meaning correctly when editing your post. In order to help you, we need the raw data, so we can play with it. Have you tried anything using `NIntegrate`? you might also want to remove the non-essential formatting options in your code. They don't matter much for your problem, and clutter the code.

Comment: Thanks, I added data and example.

Comment: I don't understand what a "discrete signal" is. Is that "time series" data that you're just mimicking with the use of `SmoothHistogram`?  If so, do you want the area under the curve with the original values or the log of the values?  The total area under a `SmoothHistogram` using the `PDF` option is exactly 1.  Does that match to the "discrete signal" data?

Comment: I got right answer for my question, below from to 2 users.
But I mean real discrete signal, which consist 20000 values and I want calcuate the area under values 2<x<4, example.  In top example, I generated random signal, because i didn't want paste a large code with the import file of true values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use [`CDF`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CDF) and avoid having to integrate:

```
cdf[x_] = CDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[r5, .1], x];
```

Then, finding the area is a simple matter of subtraction:

```
cdf[4] - cdf[2]
```

> 0.264359

This returns the same answer as using NIntegrate and PDF:

```
NIntegrate[PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[r5, .1], x], {x, 2, 4}]
```

> 0.264359

Comment: Thanks for your help, friend!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have your data, but calculating the area under the curve should be as simple as

```
NIntegrate[PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[r20, .1], x], {x, 8, 10}]
```

To fill in the corresponding area under the curve, have a look at the plot option `Filling`.

Update:  here's a start at an answer on how you can get the filling over a given range of abscissae:

```
 SeedRandom[111222];
 r5 = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[1, 2], 100];
 f = PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[r5, 0.5], x];
 Plot[{f, Piecewise[{{f, 2 < x < 4}}, _]}, {x, -8, 8},
    Filling->{2 -> {Axis, Yellow}}, PlotStyle->{Blue, Yellow}]
```

Here I've used a bit more smoothing (bw = 0.5, rather than 0.1), and I didn't bother with your special plot options.   I couldn't figure out how to properly utilize the      Opacity[]   directive to get a lower opacity for the yellow filling.

Comment: Hello, my friend, I added data and example, but I tried your solution and I think, that it is true. Thanks. But I don't find solution in helper, how filling the area between 2 and 4, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your help.